# How to assign a value to a property using an expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a class:

```
public class Item { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

And a collection of this class:

```
ICollection<Item> items;
```

Currently I have the following:

```
var item = items.Where(x => x.Name == "id").FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
    item.Value = 1;

var item = items.Where(x => x.Name == "name").FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
    item.Value = "Username";

//etc... for a number of items
```

Is it possible to an Expression and inline function to achieve the above but in much less and cleaner code?

Something like:

```
items.Set(x => x.Name == "id", value = 1);
items.Set(x => x.Name == "name", value = "username");
```

Comment: you have no Id property in your item class

Comment: Perhaps `items.Where(x => x.Name == "id").ToList().ForEach(x => x.Value = 1)`

Comment: Where clause needs `Func<T,bool>`, you can devise a Set method which can give out `Func<T,T>` and use those values to create a predicate, so by default mechanism it needs a custom code

Comment: Sounds like you should be storing these values in a dictionary, rather than an `ICollection`.  If you were storing them in the right type of collection not only would looking up the value be faster, as you wouldn't need to search through each item, but you could set the value of each of your keys with a single method call.

Comment: you can have your predicate directly inside the `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: @MongZhu it's not exactly a duplicate. those solutions don't take into account the null check. Those solutions are similar to this answer

Comment: @MongZhu i had mentioned the `FirstOrDefault` overload on a comment above. regarding the duplicate, you add a null check to those answers and you are almost back to this question. it wouldn't resolve the OPs question

Comment: @NevilleNazerane convinced, I retracted my vote. Wish a pleasant evening :) c ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(
        this ICollection<T> source, 
        Func<T, bool> predicate, 
        Action<T> action)
    {
        var item = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        if(item != null)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var collection = new List<User>()
{
    new User { Name = "Pavel", Id = 1 },
    new User { Name = "Anna", Id = 2}
};

collection.Set(q => q.Id == 1, w => w.Name = "Jacob");
```

Answer (score 1):

With slight addition to your class you can do it like this:

```
items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "id")?.SetValue(1);
```

Null-conditional operator `?.` (aka Elvis operator) protects you from the default/null value while calling `SetValue(1)` but it does not allow for an assignment i.e. you cannot use property with it.

Your class will need `SetValue` method:

```
public void SetValue(object arg)
{
    Value = arg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a solution using `.ToList()` and `.ForEach()`, but that is not very readable.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Item { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item(){
            Name = "test",
            Value = 2
        });
        items.Add(new Item(){
            Name = "id",
            Value = 0
        });

        items.Where(i => i.Name == "id").ToList().ForEach(i => i.Value = 1);
        Console.WriteLine(items[1].Name + " : " + items[1].Value);
    }
}
```

Link to fiddle: https://ideone.com/7m66rg

Comment: doesn't look like OP wanted to do this for every item.

Comment: Yeah this assumes only one item will have name=id

Comment: based on the question seems like only the first

Answer (score 0):

your syntax `items.Set(x => x.Name == "id", value = 1);` doesn't look valid. But you can use `items.Set(x => x.Name == "id", value : 1);` or `items.Set(x => x.Name == "id", 1);` if you use this:

```
public static class ItemExtensions
{

    public static void Set(this ICollection<Item> items, Func<Item, bool> predicate, object value)
    {
        var item = items.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        if (item != null)
            item.Value = value;
    }

}
```

**Explanation**

1. You are looking for a function for an existing class `ICollection`. So, you would need to create an extension function.
2. You are trying to pass something to the Linq `Where` function. Check the exact data type passed into the where. You would notice its `Func<TSource, bool> predicate`. In this case, we know `TSource` is `Item`.
3. You can also have this predicate directly inside `FirstOrDefault`